# How can I update my input to make sure it has the latest value

Tags: html, reactjs, redux

I have a react component called `productsTable` where a user can specify the number of products they want for an item and then add it to their cart. I am using a `input` field to allow them to enter the number of products. The issue I am having is that if a user enters the values for the input fields and clicks add to cart for each product, the value that setState will have is the last value entered in the input field vs having that individual input fields value. The reason this happens is the way I am using `setState` which is updated in the `onChange` of the input. Any idea on what I can do to fix this. I was thinking maybe putting the `input` as it's own seperate component so each `product` can get it's own instance of an `input`. Code is down below.

```
import { Table, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getAllProducts } from '../../redux/actions/productActions';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { addToCart } from '../../redux/actions/shoppingCartActions';

const ProductsTable = ({ searchTerm }) => {
  const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) || {};

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [input, setInput] = useState(0);

  const cartId = useSelector((state) => state.cartStatus.cartInfo.cartId);

  const handleAdd = (product, input) => {
    const isBadInput = validateInput(input);

    if (isBadInput) {
      toast.error('Invalid product amount', {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        autoClose: 1200,
      });

      return;
    }

    const myProduct = {
      productAmount: input,
      ...product,
      userId: userInfo.userId,
      cartId: cartId,
    };

    dispatch(addToCart(myProduct));

    toast.success('Product added successfuly', {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
      autoClose: 1500,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllProducts());
  }, []);

  const products = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer.products);
  const sortedProducts = sortBy(products, ({ productName }) =>
    productName.toLowerCase()
  );

  const validateInput = (inputValue) => {
    let value = parseInt(inputValue, 10);
    if (value < 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      value = value >= 0 ? value : 0;
      setInput(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='col-9'>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
            <th>Seller</th>
            <th>Amount In Stock</th>
            <th>Amount To Purchase</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortedProducts.length > 0 &&
            sortedProducts
              .filter((product) => {
                const { productName } = product;
                if (searchTerm === '') {
                  return product;
                }
                if (productName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
                  return product;
                }
              })
              .map((product) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={product.id}>
                    <td>{product.productName}</td>
                    <td>{product.productPrice}</td>
                    <td>Seller </td>
                    <td>{product.productInStock}</td>

                    <td>
                      <input
                        type='number'
                        name='input'
                        step='1'
                        onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Button
                        onClick={() => handleAdd(product, input)}
                        variant='primary'
                      >
                        Add To Cart
                      </Button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductsTable;
```

Comment: "user tries to add a bunch of products at the same time" What does this mean ?

Comment: If a user enters the values for the input fields and clicks add to cart for each product, the value that setState will have is the last value entered in the input field vs having that individual input fields value. @UmerAbbas

Comment: One way to solve your problem is to keep an array of products in the state that stores the quantity of the product, so for this use a function like `handleInputChange(product.id, event.target.value)` this way every product has it's own quantity stored in the array.

Comment: would you mind sharing pseudo code for this @UmerAbbas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who run into a similar issue, I moved the `input` field into its own component and called it in the `productsTable` component. That way there is a separate input field for each product. I had a feeling that would work originally but after trying on my own, I was able to prove it.